# Adding conditional logic (IF, THEN) in Salesforce HTML email templates

Tags: email, email-template, html, conditional, if

I'm struggling with adding IF, THEN conidition to my HTML Classic Email template and hoping someone can help.

I am trying to say if Cohort Owner's name is 'X', then post the X link, if Cohort Owner's name is 'Y', then post the Y link and if Cohort Owner's name is 'Z' then paste the Z link.

This is the statement I am using in SF that is not outputting what I'd like

```
{!IF({!Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName} = "Bob", "Boblink", " ")}
{!IF({!Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName} = "Tim", "Timlink", " ")}
{!IF({!Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName} = "Anna", "Annalink", " ")}
```

This is the output it gives me when I send an email.

```
 = "Bob", "Boblink", " ")} = "Tim", "Timlink", " ")} = "Anna", "Annalink", " ")}
```

I'd like the output to be dependent on Cohort Owner and have the output as, i.e Here is.. Annalink (if Cohort Owner is Anna)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge fields start with `{!` and end with `}`. You do not use `{!` or `}` within the merge field. In addition, you can use a [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5#CASE) statement, which is easier to read.

```
{!CASE(Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName,
  "Bob", "Boblink",
  "Tim", "Timlink",
  "Anna", "Annalink",
  "")}
```

Or, if you prefer the IF statements, you can nest them together:

```
{!IF(Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName = "Bob", "Boblink",
IF(Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName = "Tim", "Timlink",
IF(Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName = "Anna", "Annalink", " ")))}
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked like a charm. Definitely the CASE statement is easier to read and will be using that - thank you for introducing me to it :)

Comment: If I may ask a follow-up question - I'm trying to use it to display a particular hyperlink and thought this would work based on your suggestion. It just displays as blank as opposed to "this link" (hyperlinked to a specific link, i.e www.boblink.com if bob. Any thoughts? (Note the spacing between https:// and the link is just to post in the forum to show the code

{!CASE(Cohorts__c.OwnerFirstName, "Bob", <a href="https:// boblink.com">this link </a>, "Tim", <a href="https:// timlink.com">this link </a>, "Anna", <a href="https:// annalink.com">this link </a>,  "")}

Comment: @Samridhi You can use the HYPERLINK function to generate an appropriate link. `{!HYPERLINK(CASE(Cohorts__c...), 'this link')}` You can also do the HTML yourself, I'd recommend doing just the URL bit, as in `<a href="{!CASE(...)}">this link</a>`.

Comment: Thaaank you - saved me so much hand banging time against a wall!